# R: Comparing, per row in a data frame, if answers are the same as another group

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data set (data frame object) where Group no.1 has the "correct" answer and the other groups' answers should be compared to these. I want to make a new column with true=1/false=0 values, where I get a 1 if the answer is the same as in group 1 and a 0 if not. I'm guessing the ifelse function combined with something else can do this. 
Example data with expected result:

```
Time    Gr  Ans Correct
1      g1   A   NA
2      g1   B   NA
3      g1   C   NA
1      g2   A   1
2      g2   B   1
3      g2   B   0
1      g3   C   0
2      g3   B   1
3      g3   C   1
1      g4   A   1
2      g4   C   0
3      g4   B   0
```

So what I want to do is make a column, df$Correct where for each row: If Answer is identical to Answer for group1, insert 1, else insert 0.

I'm looking at "apply" or "aggregate", "identical" and "ifelse" but haven't figured out how to make R look at the column twice but in different places... Another way might be to make a new column with the correct results copied down for comparison, but there are many more variables (answer types) so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

(The question title is a bit weird, please help make it clearer if you have any suggestions!)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose your data.frame is `df`...

```
> y <- split(df$Ans, df$Gr)                                       # this splits your df based on "Gr"
> df$correct <- stack(lapply(y, function(x) x==y$g1))$values * 1  # Comparing each "Ans" to "g1"'s Ans.
> df[df$Gr=="g1", "correct"] <- NA                                # Replacing "g1"'s results with NA
> df
   Time Gr Ans correct
1     1 g1   A      NA
2     2 g1   B      NA
3     3 g1   C      NA
4     1 g2   A       1
5     2 g2   B       1
6     3 g2   B       0
7     1 g3   C       0
8     2 g3   B       1
9     3 g3   C       1
10    1 g4   A       1
11    2 g4   C       0
12    3 g4   B       0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)

y = x[Gr == "g1",]
z = x[y, on = c("Time")]
z[, Correct := ifelse(Gr == "g1", NA, abs(Ans == i.Ans))]
```